# Parameter passed in angular import opts ignored

Tags: angular, webpack, service-worker, angular-compiler

Since I want to load my `@angular/service-worker` only in production mode, I have added the following to my webpack config:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
   'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isDevBuild ? 'dev' : 'prod')
    }
})
```

However, if I try to use it as

```
imports: [
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'prod') })
]
```

then it works as expected in dev mode (i.e. if I make the equality to `'dev'` then it is used and not otherwise), but in prod mode, the service worker never loads and there is no compile-time or runtime error. Moreover, if I log it to console then the value is `true` as expected and the service worker loads if I set `enabled:true`.

I'm using this in my webpack config

```
new AngularCompilerPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module#AppModule')
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work around this by using

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isDevBuild ? 'dev' : 'prod'),
        'ISDEV': isDevBuild ? true : false,
     }
}),
```

and using the `ISDEV`parameter instead. For some reason, the AOT compiler seems to work improperly with such comparisons. I would love to know the reason!